# Вывести значение из MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

вот например чтобы вывести все значения из столбца MYSQL, у меня есть такой цикл:

```
 $baza = $mysqli->query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `user`");

                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($baza);
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($baza)) {
                               echo "$row[0] \n";
                     }
```

Он выводит все значения, а как например мне вывести значения с того же столбца , но например начиная с 100 строки?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть `limit`. Если вам нужно вывести все значения кроме первых 99 (т.е. начиная с 100), то так:

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `user` LIMIT 99,18446744073709551615;
```

Об этом говорит сама документация `MySQL`:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SQL LIMIT` позволяет вывести указанное число строк из таблицы. Оператор `SQL LIMIT` записывается всегда в конце запроса.

Оператор `LIMIT` имеет следующий синтаксис:

```
LIMIT first_row [, last_row]
```

Оператор `SQL LIMIT` выводит то количество записей, которое указано в параметре `first_row`. Если, через запятую указано значение параметра `last_row`, то будут выведены строки в диапазоне `first_row — last_row` включительно.

Ну и соответственно если вы работаете с массивом, то рекомендую использовать не `while`, а оператор `foreach` (http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php).

Конечно же можно сделать срез массива при помощи `array_slice` (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php), но делать этого я не рекомендую.

Comment: А где тут работа с массивом?

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну в данном случае в вопросе "$row"